# Compound Poisson, preliminary work in R

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, parameterization

I need help with following programming code:

Beforehand: I tried to estimate *Poisson-parameters*, but *M.L.E.* and *M.C.* do not give satisfactory results regarding actual to expected, from actuarial point of view, Poisson-model is okay.  Hence would like to "use" *Poisson-parameters* like this:

```
0.9, 0.99, 0.999, 0.9999, ...
the same with 0.8, 
... 
finally 0.1 ......
```

For the calculation of these parameters I am using:

```
Poi_para <- numeric()  
sum <- 0  
Poi <- function(n) {0.9 / 10^(n-1)} #<- I am quite happy with this formula  
for(i in 1:4)                       # 4 or 14 or 24 or ......  
{  
 Poi_para[i] <- Poi(i)  
}  
Poi_para  
[1] 9e-01 9e-02 9e-03 9e-04
```

Now, I would like to do some summation, and for this I need your help for the programming code:

```
first value shall be: 0.9  
second: 0.99 (i.e. the sum of "0.9 + 0.09")  
third: "0.9 + 0.09 + 0.009" (or, the sum of prev. line + 0.009) 
and so on.
```

Braun/Murdoch are doing similar on p. 54 with a `while()` loop, but I can't translate it into my problem.  Can anyone who could give me a hand with how to do the summation?

Poisson-parameters are next fed into the Poisson-model with the data etc.

Comment: Hi gung, it seems that you gave me a hand in bringing my question into a readable format, thanks. Could you give me an idea, how to write the programcode in the form you did? Sorry, but I did not find it in the "catalog" of how to ask question, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like programming than statistics so perhaps belongs on Stack Overflow.  In R you could try

```
n <- 4 
Poi_para <- rep(9:1, each=n) * rep((10^(1:n)-1) / (9*10^(1:n)), times=9)
```

to give

```
> Poi_para
 [1] 0.9000 0.9900 0.9990 0.9999 0.8000 0.8800 0.8880 0.8888 0.7000 0.7700
[11] 0.7770 0.7777 0.6000 0.6600 0.6660 0.6666 0.5000 0.5500 0.5550 0.5555
[21] 0.4000 0.4400 0.4440 0.4444 0.3000 0.3300 0.3330 0.3333 0.2000 0.2200
[31] 0.2220 0.2222 0.1000 0.1100 0.1110 0.1111
```

Comment: Hi Henry, thanks, exactly what I was looking for AND without using any summation as in my first attempt. I will need some time, before I fully grasp yr formula, but I already "played" with it and it is great, many thanks again. How do I get to this Stack Overflow?? Regards, Andreas

Comment: Henry, I found the Stack Overflow "site", Sorry, I should have looked before talking!!!